# Index of the current DataRow in a DataTable

Tags: asp.net

```
For Each dr As myDAL.UsersRow In data
   str.AppendLine(dr.UserName)
Next
```

In the above code, I also need to include the row index so that it's something like

```
str.AppendLine(dr.IndexNumber & " " & dr.UserName)
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S. `data` is not a `DataTable` but a generic list of `myDAL.UsersRow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If data is a `List<myDAL.UsersRow>` as you suggest, you can use a "for" loop rather than a "for each" loop:

```
for i = 0 to data.Count - 1
    str.AppendLine(i & " " & data[i].UserName)
next
```

If, however, you're implying that your "data" list is not in the same order as the original DataTable's rows, you might be able to use the [DataRowCollection.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.indexof.aspx) method to locate the row in the original table:

```
for each dr as myDAL.UsersRow in data
    str.AppendLine(dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr) & " " & dr.UserName)
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a counter variable before the ForEach loop, and increment it inside it.

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each dr As myDAL.UsersRow In data
        counter = counter + 1
        str.AppendLine(counter.ToString() & " " & dr.UserName)
    Next
```